# How to store write-once, read-rarely data

Tags: database, data-structures, architecture, storage, write-once

I have an application which produces a large amount of data, that is all written once and then unchangeable (by law), and is rarely ever read. When it is read, it is always read in its entirety, as in, all the data for 2012 is read in one shot, and either processed for reporting or output in a different format for export (or *gasp* printed). The only way to access the data is to access an entire day's worth of data, or more than one day.

This data is easily represented as either two or three relational tables, or as a long list of self-contained documents.

What is the most storage-space-efficient way to store such data in a file system? Specifically, we're thinking of using Amazon S3 (File storage) for storage, though we could use something like RDS (their version of MySQL).

My current best bet is a gzipped file with JSON data for the entire day, one file per day.

Comment: This is an architecture question.

Comment: SO is for specific programming questions. Maybe hire a solutions architect?

Comment: @MitchWheat: I have a specific programming question. What's the most storage-space efficient way to store data, when it is naturally segmented into manageable chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless my data was pure ASCII (and even if it was), I would probably choose a binary storage method like one of

- [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/)
- [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)
- [B encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode)

Comment: You make a good point, My data is mostly numeric, there's no reason for it to be stored as text.

Comment: My personal pref would probably be protocol buffers.

Comment: I'd probably go with something that has field names, like BSON. Otherwise versioning is very hard - and this data is meant to be kept for _years_.

Comment: I meant for space efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Windows Azure's [Table Storage](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/) because it allows for heterogenous structured data to be stored in a single table. Having a database-like storage will allow you to append data as needed. You can easily create new table for each year.